# NSRunLoop : Is it really idle between kCFRunLoopBeforeWaiting & kCFRunLoopAfterWaiting?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, macos, nsrunloop

I'm interested about NSRunLoop cycle, especially for main runloop.Via `CFRunLoopObserverRef`, we can know more about it :

```
CFRunLoopObserverRef observerRef = CFRunLoopObserverCreateWithHandler(NULL, kCFRunLoopAllActivities, YES, 0, ^(CFRunLoopObserverRef observer, CFRunLoopActivity activity) {
    if (activity == kCFRunLoopBeforeTimers) {
        weakSelf.runloopId += 1;
    }
    NSLog(@"RunloopId : %lu, Activity : %ld, %lf\n", (unsigned long)weakSelf.runloopId, activity, [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]);
});
CFRunLoopAddObserver(CFRunLoopGetMain(), observerRef, kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
```

We can ignore `kCFRunLoopEntry` & `kCFRunLoopExit` for main runloop, and focus on `kCFRunLoopBeforeTimers`, `kCFRunLoopBeforeSources`, `kCFRunLoopBeforeWaiting` and `kCFRunLoopAfterWaiting`.

According to [The Run Loop Sequence of Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-SW23) and [CFRunLoop.c](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-1151.16/CFRunLoop.c),

1. one loop of main runloop starts at `kCFRunLoopBeforeTimers`,
2. then `kCFRunLoopBeforeSources`,
3. after the above two events, if nothing pending, goto sleep,

so, in my opinion, when the main loop goes to sleep, it should be idle.

## Normal waiting state

Using my code above, when I open the app (in simulator) and just leave it there to keep it idle, runloop event callbacks will print out the log onto the console:

```
2016-03-08 21:58:33.522 CaptureJitterDemo[25272:1312010] RunloopId : 156, Activity : 2, 1457445513.522846
2016-03-08 21:58:33.523 CaptureJitterDemo[25272:1312010] RunloopId : 156, Activity : 4, 1457445513.522985
2016-03-08 21:58:33.523 CaptureJitterDemo[25272:1312010] RunloopId : 156, Activity : 32, 1457445513.523144
2016-03-08 21:58:49.002 CaptureJitterDemo[25272:1312010] RunloopId : 156, Activity : 64, 1457445529.002502
2016-03-08 21:58:49.002 CaptureJitterDemo[25272:1312010] RunloopId : 157, Activity : 2, 1457445529.002820
2016-03-08 21:58:49.003 CaptureJitterDemo[25272:1312010] RunloopId : 157, Activity : 4, 1457445529.003044
```

`Activity : 32` means `beforeWaiting`, while `Activity : 64` means `afterWaiting`, and between the two states the main callstack is like below:

[image]

It has nothing to do, but waiting.

## Surprising waiting state

Occasionally, I find that something might happen between `beforeWaiting` & `afterWaiting`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"begin of url request... %lf\n", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]);
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3771/9914251535_366536a515_h.jpg"]];
    if (data) {
        NSLog(@"end of url request : %lf\n", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]);
    }
}
```

when I select one row, the console prints:

```
2016-03-08 23:00:07.927 CaptureJitterDemo[25855:1334505] RunloopId : 27, Activity : 2, 1457449207.927184
2016-03-08 23:00:07.927 CaptureJitterDemo[25855:1334505] RunloopId : 27, Activity : 4, 1457449207.927399
2016-03-08 23:00:07.927 CaptureJitterDemo[25855:1334505] RunloopId : 27, Activity : 32, 1457449207.927624
2016-03-08 23:00:07.929 CaptureJitterDemo[25855:1334505] begin of url request... 1457449207.929021
2016-03-08 23:00:10.277 CaptureJitterDemo[25855:1334505] end of url request : 1457449210.276982
2016-03-08 23:00:10.278 CaptureJitterDemo[25855:1334505] RunloopId : 27, Activity : 64, 1457449210.278046
2016-03-08 23:00:10.278 CaptureJitterDemo[25855:1334505] RunloopId : 28, Activity : 2, 1457449210.278244
2016-03-08 23:00:10.278 CaptureJitterDemo[25855:1334505] RunloopId : 28, Activity : 4, 1457449210.278486
2016-03-08 23:00:10.278 CaptureJitterDemo[25855:1334505] RunloopId : 28, Activity : 32, 1457449210.278752
```

[image]

According to the logs, between `beforeWaiting` & `afterWaiting`, the app completed one url request task. This confuses me.

## My misunderstanding at first

At first, I thought that **synchronous url request on main thread would cause the main runloop goes into `waiting` state**. But later I found that the app went into `waiting` state first, then the url request occurred.

So, now it is the phenomenon that after the main runloop goes into `waiting` state, it can still make synchronous url request without waking itself up -- kidding me?

If I move the code to `viewDidAppear`:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    
    NSLog(@"begin of url request... %lf\n", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]);
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3771/9914251535_366536a515_h.jpg"]];
    if (data) {
        NSLog(@"end of url request : %lf\n", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]);
    }
}
```

the console prints:

```
2016-03-08 23:42:25.616 CaptureJitterDemo[26268:1377354] RunloopId : 0, Activity : 1, 1457451745.616474
2016-03-08 23:42:25.617 CaptureJitterDemo[26268:1377354] RunloopId : 1, Activity : 2, 1457451745.617201
2016-03-08 23:42:25.617 CaptureJitterDemo[26268:1377354] RunloopId : 1, Activity : 4, 1457451745.617346
2016-03-08 23:42:25.618 CaptureJitterDemo[26268:1377354] begin of url request... 1457451745.618176
2016-03-08 23:42:27.832 CaptureJitterDemo[26268:1377354] end of url request : 1457451747.832428
2016-03-08 23:42:27.832 CaptureJitterDemo[26268:1377354] RunloopId : 2, Activity : 2, 1457451747.832818
2016-03-08 23:42:27.832 CaptureJitterDemo[26268:1377354] RunloopId : 2, Activity : 4,
```

which seems more acceptable.

## What I really want to do

I want to calculate the time a loop cost, on main runloop, but the idle time should not be included.

A loop means:

1. If sleep not happened: `kCFRunLoopBeforeTimers` ->
   `kCFRunLoopBeforeSources` -> `kCFRunLoopBeforeTimers`;
2. If sleep happened: `kCFRunLoopBeforeTimers` -> `kCFRunLoopBeforeSources` ->
   `kCFRunLoopBeforeWaiting` -> `kCFRunLoopAfterWaiting` ->
   `kCFRunLoopBeforeTimers`;

For time cost between `kCFRunLoopBeforeWaiting` -> `kCFRunLoopAfterWaiting`:

1. if it is **normal waiting state**, the time should be excluded, because
   it is really idle;
2. else if it is **surprising waiting state**, the time should be included,
   because it does have things done;

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the **surprising waiting time** stack trace, it looks like the Core Animation flush is happening as a result of observing the run loop. My guess is that it is observing the `kCFRunLoopBeforeWaiting` activity and ends up triggering `didSelectRow..` as a result. Since the call is blocking, the run loop stays on that step (step 6 in Sequence of Events) until the semaphore is signaled.

To achieve what you want to do - create a separate observer for `kCFRunLoopBeforeWaiting` and `kCFRunLoopAfterWaiting` and in the 4th parameter (order) of `CFRunLoopObserverCreateWithHandler` pass in `LONG_MAX` and `0` respectively.

Also, it's better to use `CACurrentMediaTime()` over `[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]` since it is monotonic.